# Mongodb query using db.collection.find() method 100 times faster than using db.collection.aggregate()?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection testData has some 4 milion documents with the identical structure:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5932c56571f5a268cea12226"), 
"x" : 1.0, 
"text" : "w592cQzC5aAfZboMujL3knCUlIWgHqZNuUcH0yJNS9U4", 
"country" : "Albania", 
"location" : {
    "longitude" : 118.8775183, 
    "latitude" : 75.4316019
}}
```

The collection is indexed on (country, location.longitude) pair.

The following two queries, which I would consider identical and which produce identical output, differ in execution time by a factor of 100:

```
db.testData.aggregate(  
[ 
    { $match : {country : "Brazil"} }, 
    { $sort : { "location.longitude" : 1 } },
    { $project : {"_id" : 0, "country" : 1, "location.longitude" : 1} }
]);
```

(this one produces output within about 6 seconds for the repeated query and about 120 seconds for the first-time query)

```
db.testData.find(
    { country : "Brazil" }, 
    {"_id" : 0, "country" : 1, "location.longitude" : 1}
).sort(
    {"location.longitude" : 1} 
);
```

(this one produces output within 15 milliseconds for the repeated query and about 1 second for the first-time query).

What am I missing here? Thanx for any feedback.

Comment: You're missing the fact that the aggregate is not the same as a find.  Yes, for your query you should use find.  If you were actually doing aggregations then you would use the aggregate framework instead.  It's slower because it's optimized for different things, and probably is using a cursor under the hood in order to allow for those things.

Comment: @Paul - Thanx for the prompt reply. I was thinking about using aggregation framework for majority of queries (I am moving my app from MySQL to MongoDB) as it seems more versatile, and I need some calculation along the line, but this difference in speed is a big drawback to that plan...

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Have you used the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) tools to investigate the differences in the execution plans for your two queries?

Comment: @Vince Yes, I did. Both of them claim to be using the index provided. I also tried the aggregate() query without index, the performance in that case is (as one would expect) even much worse, several minutes for the same query.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB find operation is used to fetch documents from a collection according to filters .
MongoDB aggregation groups values from a collection and performs computation on group of values through execution of stages in pipeline and return computed result.

MongoDB find operation performs speedily as compared to aggregation operation as aggregate operation encapsulates multiple stages into pipeline  which performs computation on data stored into collection with each stage's output serving as input to another stage and return processed result.
Mongo DB find operation returns a cursor to fetched documents that match filters and cursor is iterated to access document.

According to above mentioned description  we need to fetch only those  documents where value of country key is Brazil and sort documents according to values of longitude key in ascending order which can be accomplished easily using MongoDB find operation.

Comment: Umm No. This is actually far more of a broad question, and frankly not much of an attempt at an answer really. Too be of any use any question and answer should be "empirical". Question and Answer should show reproducible examples of where differences occur and why. I have not done a "deep dive" in the code of late, but at the time of MongoDB 2.6 there were significant changes made to the query engine, partly in order to see that standard `.find()` and `.aggregate()` were using the same things for these basic operations. There is no empirical reason or response for any difference here.

Comment: @Rubin Thanx for the reply. Actually, with these queries I was just testing the two methods (find vs aggregate) for the speed in filtering of required documents according to specified criteria. Subsequently I wanted to add the other aggregation stages to work on the documents filtered in this stage. However, if aggregate() is so massively slower  than find(), it makes no sense whatsoever to use it at all for initial filtering. And this is only a very tiny collection for big data standards (about 30 Mb of data) I dare not think what would happen if I attempted this with serious Gb collections..